# Seeing if JButton is clicked from parent class

Tags: java, swing, awt, jbutton, actionlistener

I am working on a project in that I am managing multiple windows in the main class. As you can tell from the title, I have a problem with JButtons in the windows.
The main method will wait for one specific button to be pressed:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    ButtonWindow bw = new ButtonWindow();
    while(bw.buttonClicked() == false);
    System.out.println("ok cool");
}
```

Meanwhile, the button's ActionListener will trigger the boolean d (the one the method buttonClicked() returns) to be set true.

```
public boolean d = false;
public ButtonWindow(){
    JPanel cp;
    JButton b;
    setContentPane(cp = new JPanel());
    cp.add(b = new JButton("Click me"));
    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            d = true;
        }
    });
    setSize(200, 200);
    setVisible(true);
}
public boolean buttonClicked() {
    return d;
}
```

Now, it seems as if the main method is stuck in the while loop. How is this possible, since "d" *had* been changed (I checked it in with an extra "System.out.println("" + d);" in the button's ActionListener)?

Thanks in advance

Oh, and also, is there any smarter way of doing this? I don't think continuously calling this method is the most practical thing to do, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am managing multiple windows in the main class.

AN application should only have a single JFrame and the main window for the application.

For secondary windows you would generally use a `modal JDialog`. Execution will not continue until the dialog is closed.

In many cases you can use a JOptionPane to manage the dialog for you. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    ButtonWindow bw = new ButtonWindow();       
}
```

And

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
if(e.getSource().getText().equals("Click me"))
System.out.println("ok cool");

}
```

**Second Approach:-**

Make your `flag` variable *static*, create new thread class, and loop using the thread which continuously checks class `flag` variable value. You can also make your `flag` variable an *instance variable* but in that case, your *object ref* will have to be shared across threads.